# Defensive Skils

Tags: learning, defense

```
 I want to improve my chess defensive abilities.
```

If you have any recommendation, any suggestion, learning technique, study plans would be appreciated.

Comment: See also http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/ways-to-improve-defensive-skills

Answer (score 0):

A reader of NM Dan Heisman's column Novice Nook asked:

**Question** What books do you recommend for defense in chess.

**Answer** It depends on what you mean by defense. **The most important
defense (see The Most Common and Important Use of Tactics) is just making
sure your moves are safe.** So that means any good book covering basic tactics
are also the best books about defense. They work if you ask "Is my candidate
move safe?" and look to see if that move would result in a position that gives
your opponent one of those safety patterns to win material or checkmate you.
If so, then you likely reject that candidate move, and prevention is the best
defense.
If you are talking about advanced defensive ideas then Soltis's book The Art
of Defense and GM Aagaard's Practical Chess Defence come to mind. **But
unless your rating is 1900+, the type of defense I mention in my article above
is way more important.**